# How to stop time out?

Tags: javascript

i am stuck
When i open page  after 2 sec i want to show random item for 1 sec. And than repeat it again. But when i hover item i want stop animation.
how can i do it in a right way?
at that moment i have this solution

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("triger");

const getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
console.log(window.TIMERS)
const run = () => {
  let random = getRandomInt(3);
  element[random].classList.add("hover");
  setTimeout(() => {
    element[random].classList.remove("hover");
    return setTimeout(run, 2000);
  }, 1000);
};

const timeID = setTimeout(run, 2000);
console.log(timeID)
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("triger_wrap")[0];
a.addEventListener("mouseenter",  () => {
  console.log('a')
  clearTimeout(timeID)
});
```

will be glad any help

https://codepen.io/Timonck/pen/BaLKrBw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom you're clearing `timeID` but the function itself already loops at the `return setTimeout(run, 2000);` line.

You need to clear the actual timeout inside the function. In the edit below it works as you wanted with the exception of requiring another line of code after the two `clearTimeouts` in order to remove the `.hover` class from the element which currently has it when we stop the timeout.

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("triger");
let timeout;

const getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
const run = () => {
  let random = getRandomInt(3);
  element[random].classList.add("hover");
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    element[random].classList.remove("hover");
    return setTimeout(run, 2000);
  }, 1000);
};

const timeID = setTimeout(run, 2000);
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("triger_wrap")[0];
a.addEventListener("mouseenter",  () => {
  clearTimeout(timeID)
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // find element with .hover class and remove it
});
```